# Evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^N {n \choose k} $

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Evaluate to get a closed form solution.

I encountered this by rearranging the below equation which I also need some help solving:
 $\sum_{n=1}^N n {n \choose k} $

I'm not very good at solving generating functions but I believe the right approach is to rearrange the terms in order to get some sort of recursive relation.

If solving the title equation is not the right approach in order to solve the equation in the body please let me know!

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: Yes, to get a closed form!

Comment: In order to avoid downvotes and get more upvotes, you can try to include your work in the question.